# Menu and Text over a banner image, responsive

Tags: html

I'm creating a webpage but I am having some problems with responsiveness.

Right under my logo, there is a large image. (1000 by 550 px) Over that image, I want to place a menu - and I think I've worked that out with `position: absolute`. However, I want to use an introduction text, and I cant figure out how to do that.

Could I just use a TextBox with absolute and z-index?  Otherwise, how can I add the image as a background image and make it responsive?

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100%;
```

That would make your background image responsive. But only if the container itself is responisve though. A more exact answer would require a fiddle or at least some html and css.

Comment: thanks, I did try that and yes that does work, however I can only see the top of the image, and if I try to add height it wont be responsive



.bannerimg{
 background-size:100%;
 background-image:url(../../../assets/grfx/start_img.png); 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }

Comment: .bannerimg{
 background-size:100%;
 background-image:url(../../../assets/grfx/start_img.png); 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }

Comment: and yes the container is repsonsive

Comment: I meant on top of the Picture I want to Place the menu and the text, but I Think you already figured that ;)